# Difficult ratio test for sequence $\frac{2^n - 3n^3}{1-4^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, ratio

I figured this required the ratio test to do. First I have:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{2^{n+1}-3(n+1)^3}{1-4^{n+1}}  \frac{1-4^n}{2^n -3n^3}\right |$$

Then I canceled out $2^n$ and $4^n$ from the top and bottom and was left with:

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left |\frac{2-3(n+1)^3}{4-3n^3}\right |$$

and got stuck.

Comment: Please consider using MathJax for better visibility. Else users will down vote and eventually close this. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial.

Comment: is my edit what you want to say?

Comment: Yes sorry, I was trying to figure it out but I'm not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use limit comparison with the sequence $2^n/4^n=1/2^n$?

But if you're a glutton for punishment, we can use the Ratio Test:

$$
\left|\frac{2^{n+1}-3(n+1)^3}{1-4^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{1-4^n}{2^n-3n^3} \right|=\left|\frac{2^{n+1}-3(n+1)^3}{2^n-3n^3}\cdot\frac{4^n-1}{4^{n+1}-1} \right|
$$
$$
=\left|\frac{2-3(n+1)^3 2^{-n}}{1-3n^3 2^{-n}}\cdot\frac{1-4^{-n}}{4-4^{-(n+1)}} \right|
$$Worth showing: if $r>1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^k/r^n=0$ for any $k$. Taking the limit, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{2-3(n+1)^3 2^{-n}}{1-3n^3 2^{-n}}\cdot\frac{1-4^{-n}}{4-4^{-(n+1)}} \right| = \frac{2-0}{1-0}\cdot \frac{1-0}{4-0}=\frac{1}{2}<1
$$